# How do I sum up all remaing amount after get max value from array?

Tags: php, arrays

I hesitated to this question either should I ask or not. I think that this is much more logical question. But, I can't really figure it out.

I have a array that may include

```
$programFees = [100,200,100,500,800,800]
```

I can get max value from this array using `max($programFees)`. If I have 2 max value like `800,800`, I want to take one only. I realized that php `max` can solve this.

But, I want to sum up all remaining amount from that array.

e.g

```
$maxProgramFees = max($programFees); 
//I got 800 and remaining amount is [100,200,100,500,800]
```

My total amount should be `1700`. Which approach should I use to get this amount?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort the array, grab the largest, then shift the array to get the remainder values. Add those values

```
<?php 
$programFees = [100, 200, 100, 500, 800, 800];
rsort($programFees); //sort high -> low

$highest = $programFees[0]; // 800
array_shift($programFees); // remove the highest value

$sum = array_sum($programFees); // 1700
```

[`rsort()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php)

[`array_shift()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

[`array_sum()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Comment: What a brilliant idea!

Comment: `array_shift()` will return the first value, so you can simplify a little with `$highest = array_shift($programFees);`

Answer (score 1):

@helllomatt has already provided a very good answer, however, if you cannot modify the array order for some reason you may want to try something like this.

```
$programFees = [100,200,100,500,800,800];
$maxProgramFees = max($programFees);
$sum = array_sum(array_diff($programFees, array($maxProgramFees)));
```

I would assume the `rsort()` answer would be the faster option.